# Toast Notification in Mobx Store? Bad Practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have an input that is a file upload, now when the `onChange` event happens the file size is extracted out and the size is checked.

Is it bad practice if the size is larger then I can accept it would show a toast error.

I am generating the toast error in the store, I am not sure if I should change it so the toast error is generated in the react component.

```
<input
  className="file-input"
  type="file"
  name="resume"
  accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  onChange={event => myStore.fileUpload(event)}
/>

@action
fileUpload(event) {
  // some other code, like extracting out the data if all checks pass.
  toast.error(`Files cannot exceed ${sizeLimitMb} MB`, { autoClose: 60000 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

If you didn't have a UI, would you still need to handle an upload failure? I'll assume that for your use case, the answer is **`yes`**.

This means that you need a mechanism in your app, at the "use case" level, to indicate a failure. It could be a mobx observable or just returning a rejected promise from your file uploader, ...

Now, how you present a failure warning to the user is a separate concern (eg: through UI toast). Plus you might want to do other things when such issue happens, like logging it, etc.

So, one way you could solve this and keep separation of concerns intact, is to have a business model like `FileUploader` which sole purpose is to upload files,  completely unaware of UI, notifications, etc. But, it should return in one way or another the success or failure of its operations.

Then you can handle this failure to show a toast separately, with a mobx store, a UI notification / toast service, etc...